# Can we get some math markup in here?

Tags: feature-request

For questions like [this one](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1144/can-a-river-be-put-under-enough-pressure-to-jet-straight-up-for-a-mile), the lack of good support for math equations makes things difficult to explain or follow. It would be nice to remedy this, especially for hard science answers.

Comment: @Mourdos: Thank you.

Comment: You could add your example question to the original feature request. The more examples we have the better the chance we'll eventually get MathJax.